# Erro de JSON via POST com Flask-RESTful e SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Estou criando uma API em Flask-RESTful e SQLAlchemy

Mas quando vou fazer um POST na API, recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro
"sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (builtins.TypeError) Not a boolean value: 'False'"

Na tabela a coluna criei dessa forma

```
paid_received = database.Column(database.Boolean, default=False, server_default="false")
```

e o JSON estou enviado assim
`"paid_received": false`

o que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Se você fizer o POST enviando o valor de `paid_received` como um inteiro `0` ou `1` ela completa com sucesso? Caso positivo acredito que o erro possa estar relacionado a [esta issue](https://github.com/spotify/luigi/issues/2347).

Comment: Se eu passar ```0``` ou ```1``` o erro permanece igual

Answer (score 0):

Consegui rsolver meu problema. Não sei se é a melhor forma ou a forma mais correta. Mas quando passado o valor via JSON `0` ou `1`

No meu método consrutor
antes estava `self.paid_received = paid_received`
anterando para `self.paid_received = int(paid_received)`
resolveu o meu problema